# Writing and reading file in same script

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am studying sockets in Python 3.

I captured data with a socket and saved it to a file. Then using a regex to get something from the same file.

I know how to use `with open as` but prefer the explicit `open` and `close` methods to avoid having an additional block spacing.

This is a section of the code.

Is this the right way? Do I have the open the file in writing mode, close it. Then opening again in reading mode and close it again?

```
fhandle = open('stream_data.txt', 'w')
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    fhandle = write(data.decode())

mysock.close()
fhandle.close()

fhandle = open('stream_data.txt', 'r')

for line in fhandle:
    match = re.match(r'...'

    (some other awesome code here)

fhandle.close()
```

Comment: Depending on how much data is involved, you could store the socket data in a `list` (or other) container initially, then process and write it to the output file.

Comment: I don't see what's your problem with `with` blocks but yes, if you insist doing it this way, there nothing wrong with the approach. You could open the file once in `a+` mode and then `fhandle.seek(0)` to get back to the beginning but you won't gain much from that.

Comment: "avoid having an additional block spacing"? Suggest you quickly get over that (or put it in a separate function). `with` also will close the file if an exception occurs, which requires a lot more code to do manually.